# Why do we substract the longitude of ascending node to the argument of periapsis in orbital mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I'm having trouble finding a satisfying answer to the following question:

To describe perfectly a Keplerian orbit, one needs 6 orbital parameters: $a$ the semi-major axis, $e$ the eccentricity, $i$ the inclination, $\omega$ the argument of periapsis, $\Omega$ the longitude of ascending node and $\nu$ the true anomaly.

We sometimes see corner plots in scientific papers discussing orbital mechanics and orbital elements predictions where **$\omega$ and $\Omega$ are not represented separately but jointly as $\Omega-\omega$ and $\Omega+\omega$.**

**Is there a specific reason for such a representation?** I can't figure out what $\Omega-\omega$ and $\Omega+\omega$ represent in terms of angular quantities.

If one of you knows, I'd be glad to hear an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A node in [orbital elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements) is the intersection of some reference plane (e.g., the [ecliptic plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic)) with the plane defined by the orbit of said object.  The [ascending node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude_of_the_ascending_node) is where the intersection occurs on the northward-bound part of the orbital object's trajectory.  The [argument of periapsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_of_periapsis), $\omega$, is the angle between the ascending node and the periapsis vector, $\mathbf{r}_{p}$.  The longitude of the ascending node, $\Omega$, is the angle between some reference direction (e.g., [First Point of Aries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Point_of_Aries)) and the ascending node.  The [true anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_anomaly), $\nu$, is the angular position along the orbital trajectory of the object.  The true longitude is then defined as:
$$
\lambda = \Omega + \omega + \nu_{o} \tag{0}
$$
where $\nu_{o}$ is the true anomaly at some defined reference [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(astronomy)) (e.g., J2000).

The [longitude of the periapsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude_of_the_periapsis) is defined as:
$$
\varpi = \Omega + \omega \tag{1}
$$
describes the longitude of the periapsis of an orbital body if the inclination of the orbit were zero.

From inspection, I am not sure to what the parameter $\Omega - \omega$ refers, however.

[image: Courtesy of Wikimedia Commons]

## **References**

- Fränz, M. and D. Harper "Heliospheric coordinate systems," *Planet. Space Sci.* **50**, pp. 217--233, doi:10.1016/S0032-0633(01)00119-2, 2002.